# How to automatically redirect category pages (301) when changing the location of a category in the hierarchy

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

How to get it so when you change location of the category it automatically 301's to the new category location.

Example> I give child a parent

a) /category/child > b) /category/parent/child

Both URLs still exist when infact (a) should redirect to (b)

Currently wordpress displays both as 200 which is creating duplicate content.

Comment: Did you check the canonical URL of the `/category/parent/child` page in the header tags? If the concern is an SEO penalty then that concern is unwarranted due to the canonical URL tags

Comment: @TomJNowell Makes sense. Thanks.